# Conflicting parameter names in bash script

Tags: bash, scope

I tried mimic the solution provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510673/find-and-kill-a-process-in-one-line-using-bash-and-regex), which finds and kills a process, and developed the following script which ssh to a list of machines specified in the input arguments and kill the desired process.

```
for node in "$@"; do
  ssh $node "kill $(ps aux | grep '[s]omeprocess' | awk '{print $2}')"
done
```

The variable `$2` used in the `awk '{print $2}'` should be the second parameter passed by the `grep [s]omeprocess`.  However, it seems that the second input argument of the whole script is used instead (Am I wrong on this part).  Can I know how my `awk '{print $2}'` can really get the second parameter passed by the previous `grep` operation? Or, is there a nicer way to find and kill a process across multiple machines? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$(ps ..)` and the `$2` will be expanded on the client side, not the server side. You should escape them:

```
ssh $node "kill \$(ps aux | grep '[s]omeprocess' | awk '{print \$2}')"
```

But instead of grepping through ps, you should just use `pkill`, as in `pkill someprocess`.

Comment: Thank you very much, can I further know where I can find more detail descriptions about `$` parameters and `\$` parameters?

Comment: Oh oh, I think I got your point. By adding `\`, it will pass the actual dollar sign to the target machine, and the interpretation of the dollar sign variable will then happen in the target machine.  Am I right at this part?

Comment: Exactly right. If you want to know more about when and how to quote and escape, there's a chapter on that in [The Linux Command Line](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php), a free downloadable ebook.

Comment: +1. @keelar: Please also note, that `ps aux | grep` is never a good idea, except for visually seeing the output. because the text someprocess can be anywhere in the command line. At least try to refine ps command. But better, use `pkill` or `killall` :)