# Kill OSX menubar process

Tags: macos, kill, menubar, kill-process

I have several menubar programs/processes/applications that start up automatically. I would like to be able to turn them all off with a single command or script; there are times when bandwidth is limited or restricted and they cause (or at least contribute to) the spinning beach ball of death.  Currently, I close each one individually by hand.

Following the [answer(s) here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510673/find-and-kill-a-process-in-one-line-using-bash-and-regex) I am able to easily find and target a process to be killed.  But, is there an indicator for a menubar process?  When I do find one by looking through the active processes and kill it (manually) it immediately gets started up again. The [comments on this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/231517/how-can-i-quit-frozen-spotlight-without-rebooting-my-computer) seem to mean that the answers didn't work, and I dont want to kill the entire menubar.

Specifically, the processes I have and want to shutdown are Dropbox, Google Drive, and Evernote.

Comment: `killall SystemUIServer` doesn't kill the DropBox menu: after the UIServer comes backup, the DropBox menu still hangs. This doesn't work either: http://superuser.com/questions/648696/how-to-stop-and-start-dropbox-app-in-apple-terminal investigating further.

Comment: `killall Dropbox` works when you got the spinning wheel. Otherwise the answer I linked above does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks [@Jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29290/jeroen-wiert-pluimers) the answer at https://superuser.com/questions/648696/how-to-stop-and-start-dropbox-app-in-apple-terminal did work for me.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Dropbox" to quit'
```

Just substitute in the application to quit.