# AWK - Remove last item out of list

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk

I'm trying to get the PID's of a certain service. I'm trying to do that with the following command:

```
ps aux | grep 'DynamoDBLocal' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Gives output:

```
1021
1022
1161
```

This returns me 3 PID's, 2 of the service that I want, and 1 for the grep it just did. I would like to remove the last PID (the one from the grep) out of the list.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There is a nice approach to this topic in http://stackoverflow.com/a/3510850/1983854 . It is the same, but over there they also call the `kill` to kill the process.

Comment: Note that `grep re | awk '{print field}` can be replaced by `awk '/re/ {print field}'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `pgrep`, it is the correct tool in this case:

```
pgrep 'DynamoDBLocal'
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `grep -v`:

```
ps aux | grep 'DynamoDBLocal' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
```

If you have [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) in your system

```
pgrep DynamoDBLocal
```

Answer (score 3):

You can say:

```
ps aux | grep '[D]ynamoDBLocal' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 3):

With a single call to `awk`

```
ps aux | awk '!/awk/ && /DynamoDBLocal/{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `pidof`, it should give you the `pid` directly.

```
pidof DynamoDBLocal
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering the original question: *How to remove lines from output*:

```
ps aux | grep 'DynamoDBLocal' | awk '{print $2}' | head --lines=-1
```

**`head`** allows you to view the X (default 10) first lines of whatever comes in. Given a value X with minus prepended it shows all but the last X lines. The 'inverse' is `tail`, btw (when you are interested in the **last** X lines).

However, given your specific problem of looking for PIDs, I recommend `pgrep` (perreals answer).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that `ps aux | grep '...'` is the right way.

But assuming that it is right way, you could do

```
ps aux | grep '...' | awk '{ if (prev) print prev; prev=$2 }'
```