# How to choose the first result on shell script

Tags: bash

I want to look for a specific process and then kill it (in a script).

I'm doing `ps -fu user | grep matching_string` but this is returning me two rows: one for the expected pid and another for the pid of the grep.

If the result were two columns, I would use awk to pick the first one. But I don't know how to pick the first result when they are returned as row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this trick:

```
ps -fu user | grep matching_strin[g]
```

This way, the `grep` match won't appear.

How does it work? (see [Find and kill a process in one line using bash and regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3510850/1983854) for more detail).

- With `ps -fu user | grep matching_string` it lists all the processes having `grep matching_string`, so that includes the `grep` itself.
- Doing `ps -fu user | grep matching_strin[g]` you add a regular expression that makes `grep` skip the `grep` itself. Why? Because the process name is `grep matching_strin[g]` and does not match the literal `matching_string`.

Comment: This worked. For example I wrote [j]ava and it didn't show the grep command. I'm going to accept yours, as it was the first I read and worked. 7 mins left.

Comment: Yes! You can place it whenever you want, the point is to add a regex so that `grep` does not match its own process.

Answer (score 2):

How about `pkill`?

```
pkill -U user-id process-name
```