# Can't find documents with MediaWiki 1.21 with the Lucene-search extension

Tags: search, cron, mediawiki

We're running MediaWiki 1.21 on Ubuntu 12.04.3 with the Lucene-search extension 2.1.3 (from its build.properties file).

I followed the instructions for a [Single Host Setup](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLucene-search#Single_Host_Setup_.28MediaWiki_.26_Lucene-Search_On_The_Same_Host.29) (using *ant* to build the jar), and *Setting Up Suggestions for the Search Box*.  Things seemed to be working just fine.  However, new documents aren't being matched by the type-ahead search feature.  Looking at the filesystem, I see that there are various items in the application's *indexes* directory:

```
$ cd /usr/local/search/lucene-search-2/indexes
$ ls -l
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 Aug 20  2013 import
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Apr 14 06:42 index
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 14 06:41 search
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4096 Aug 20  2013 snapshot
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 20  2013 status
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Aug 20  2013 update
```

We have a daily cron job that runs the Lucene-search *build* command, which dumps the wiki database as xml, and then modifies files in the *import* and *snapshot* folders.  I noticed that the job reads from the *search* folder, which contains symbolic links to the *update* folder:

```
$ ls -l search/
total 24
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 70 Feb 12 21:39 wikidb -> /usr/local/search/lucene-search-2/indexes/update/wikidb/20140212064727
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 73 Feb 12 21:39 wikidb.hl -> /usr/local/search/lucene-search-2/indexes/update/wikidb.hl/20140212064727
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 76 Apr 14 06:41 wikidb.links -> /usr/local/search/lucene-search-2/indexes/update/wikidb.links/20140414064150
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 77 Feb 12 21:39 wikidb.prefix -> /usr/local/search/lucene-search-2/indexes/update/wikidb.prefix/20140212064728
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 78 Feb 12 21:39 wikidb.related -> /usr/local/search/lucene-search-2/indexes/update/wikidb.related/20140212064713
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 76 Feb 12 21:39 wikidb.spell -> /usr/local/search/lucene-search-2/indexes/update/wikidb.spell/20140212064740
```

Only the *wikidb.links* entry is current.  The others are a couple of months old, which makes me think I missed something in how our daily cron task is setup.  Here's the job:

```
#!/bin/sh
log=/var/log/lucene-search-2-cron.log
(
  echo "Building wiki lucene-search indexes ..."
  cd /usr/local/search/lucene-search-2
  ./build

  echo "Stopping the lsearchd service..."
  service lsearchd stop

  # ok, so stopping the service apparently doesn't mean that the processes are gone, whack them manually
  # See tip on using the "[x]yz" character class option so you don't need the additional "grep -v xyz":
  #   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510673/find-and-kill-a-process-in-one-line-using-bash-and-regex
  echo "Killing any lucene-search processes that didn't terminate..."
  kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep '[l]search' | awk '{print $2}')

  echo "Starting the lsearchd service..."
  service lsearchd start

) > $log 2>&1
```

And here's the service script /etc/init.d/lsearchd:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:             lsearchd
# Required-Start:       $syslog
# Required-Stop:        $syslog
# Default-Start:        2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:         1
# Short-Description:    Start the Lucene Search daemon
# Description:          Provide a Lucene Search backend for MediaWiki. Copied by John Ericson from: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t
=1476445
### END INIT INFO

# Set to install directory of lucense-search. For example: /usr/local/lucene-search-2.1.3
LUCENE_SEARCH_DIR="/usr/local/search/lucene-search-2"

# Set username for daemon to run as. Can also use syntax "username:groupname" to also specify group for daemon to run as. For example: me:me
RUN_AS_USER="lsearchd"

OPTIONS="-configfile $LUCENE_SEARCH_DIR/lsearch.conf"

test -x $LUCENE_SEARCH_DIR/lsearchd || exit 0

test -n "$RUN_AS_USER" && CHUID_ARG="--chuid $RUN_AS_USER" || CHUID_ARG=""

if [ -f "/etc/default/lsearchd" ] ; then
    . /etc/default/lsearchd
fi

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case "$1" in
  start)
    cd $LUCENE_SEARCH_DIR
    log_begin_msg "Starting Lucene Search Daemon..."
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --chdir $LUCENE_SEARCH_DIR --background $CHUID_ARG --exec $LUCENE_SEARCH_DIR/lsearchd -- $OPT
IONS
    log_end_msg $?
    ;;
  stop)
    log_begin_msg "Stopping Lucene Search Daemon..."
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry 2 --chdir $LUCENE_SEARCH_DIR $CHUID_ARG --exec $LUCENE_SEARCH_DIR/lsearchd
    log_end_msg $?
    ;;
  restart)
    $0 stop
    sleep 1
    $0 start
    ;;
  reload|force-reload)
    log_begin_msg "Reloading Lucene Search Daemon..."
    start-stop-daemon --stop -signal 1 --chdir $LUCENE_SEARCH_DIR $CHUID_ARG --exec $LUCENE_SEARCH_DIR/lsearchd
    log_end_msg $?
    ;;
  status)
    status_of_proc $LUCENE_SEARCH_DIR/lsearchd lsearchd && exit 0 || exit $?
    ;;
  *)
   log_success_msg "Usage: /etc/init.d/lsearchd {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status}"
   exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

**Update #1:**

I deleted the *update* directory and ran the *build* command manually from the console as root.  As expected, it only generated the *update/wikidb.links* entry, none of the other folders exist.  I reviewed my earlier setup notes, and don't see anything different, so how did those folders get created, and how do they get maintained?

**Update #2:**

I retraced my steps from the initial install, and couldn't see anything I missed.  So on a chance, I stopped the service and ran *lsearchd* from the console, and *it created the missing directories!*  So I terminated the process and tried things again: deleted the *indexes* folder and ran the cron script from the console as root.  I confirmed that when run this way, *lsearchd DID NOT create the missing directories.*  And of course, now I remember that I had run lsearchd from the console when initially setting things up, verifying that it was getting client queries for the wiki's Search input field.  And these are the indexes it had been using for the lookups, which explains why new documents are not included.

Here is what the command looks like when run as a service:

```
$ ps -ef | grep [l]search
lsearchd 10192     1  0 14:02 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /usr/local/search/lucene-search-2/lsearchd -configfile /usr/local/search/lucene-search-2/lsearch.conf
lsearchd 10198 10192  0 14:02 ?        00:00:01 java -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:///usr/local/search/lucene-search-2/LuceneSearch.jar -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=AMWikiBugz -jar /usr/local/search/lucene-search-2/LuceneSearch.jar -configfile /usr/local/search/lucene-search-2/lsearch.conf
```

So the remaining question is:

**Why does lsearchd NOT create the directories when run as a service?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This was a permissions issue.*  d'oh!

The cron job and service init scripts all execute as root, however the service *process* is instantiated as the *lsearchd* user.  Once I changed ownership of /usr/local/search/lucene-search-2/indexes/ and all subdirectories to be owned by *lsearchd:lsearchd*, the lsearchd process was able to create the missing directories when run via the service under cron.

It would have helped if something along the way had logged an error message to syslog indicating that it couldn't write to the target folder.