# How do i store the output of a bash command in a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm trying to write a simple script for killing a process. I've already read [Find and kill a process in one line using bash and regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510673/find-and-kill-a-process-in-one-line-using-bash-and-regex) so please don't redirect me to that.

This is my code:

```
LINE=$(ps aux | grep '$1')
PROCESS=$LINE | awk '{print $2}'
echo $PROCESS
kill -9 $PROCESS
```

I want to be able to run something like

`sh kill_proc.sh node` and have it run

`kill -9 node`

But instead what I get is

```
kill_process.sh: line 2: User: command not found
```

I found out that when I log `$PROCESS` it is empty.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `PROCESS=$LINE | awk '{print $2}'` is wrong. Compare it to the first line.

Comment: @EtanReisner if i try `PROCESS=$(LINE | awk '{print $2}')` i still get an error `LINE`: command not found`

Comment: You still need to prefix `$` to `LINE` (and `echo` it into the pipeline): `$(echo $LINE | awk...)`

Comment: @MarcB the `var=$(command)` is better...

Comment: @chepner why do i need to add `echo`?

Comment: In  the `LINE=$(ps aux | grep '$1')` the `'$1'` isnt expanded. use double quotes like `LINE=$(ps aux | grep "$1")`

Comment: use `killall` or `pkill` instead of rolling your own.

Comment: `PROCESS=$(awk '{print $2}' <<<"$LINE")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PROCESS=$(echo "$LINE" | awk '{print $2}')
```

or

```
PROCESS=$(ps aux | grep "$1" | awk '{print $2}')
```

I don't know why you're getting the error you quoted.  I can't reproduce it.  When you say this:

```
PROCESS=$LINE | awk '{print $2}'
```

the shell expands it to something like this:

```
PROCESS='mayoff  10732 ...' | awk '{print $2}'
```

(I've shortened the value of `$LINE` to make the example readable.)

The first subcommand of the pipeline sets variable `PROCESS`; this variable-setting command has no output so `awk` reads EOF immediately and prints nothing.  And since each subcommand of the pipeline runs in a subshell, the setting of `PROCESS` takes place only in a subshell, not in the parent shell running the script, so `PROCESS` is still not set for later commands in your script.

(Note that some versions of `bash` can run the last subcommand of the pipeline in the current shell instead of in a subshell, but that doesn't affect this example.)

Instead of setting `PROCESS` in a subshell and feeding nothing to `awk` on standard input, you want to feed the value of `LINE` to `awk` and store the result in `PROCESS` in the current shell.  So you need to run a command that writes the value of `LINE` to its standard output, and connects that standard output to the standard input of `awk`.  The `echo` command can do this (or the `printf` command, as chepner pointed out in his answer).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `echo` (or `printf`) to actually put the value of `$LINE` onto the standard input of the `awk` command.

```
LINE=$(ps aux | grep "$1")
PROCESS=$(echo "$LINE" | awk '{print $2}')
echo $PROCESS
kill -9 $PROCESS
```

There's no need use `LINE`; you can set `PROCESS` with a single line

```
PROCESS=$(ps aux | grep "$1" | awk '{print $2}')
```

or better, skip the `grep`:

```
PROCESS=$(ps aux | awk -v pname="$1" '$1 ~ pname {print $2}')
```

Finally, don't use `kill -9`; that's a last resort for debugging faulty programs. For any program that you didn't write yourself, `kill "$PROCESS"` should be sufficient.

Comment: A bit unrelated but... I'm not able to actually kill the process. My script is no longer throwing errors, but the process is not getting killed even when run with `sudo`. thoughts?

Comment: Put `set -x` at the top of the script to get a better idea of what it's doing.  This command makes the shell echo each command before running it.

Comment: @dopatraman show the full process line. Contains an `Z` in the `STAT` field? (Z = Zombie - unkillable). Or maybe, you want kill a process what waits for some kernel I/O.

Comment: @chepner the `kill "$PROCESS"` will kill a processes, when the `$PROCESS` will contain multiple `PIDs`? (e.g. the grep founds more processes)... In this case IMHO the quotes are not needed.

Comment: Good point. I rarely write code where I would use a single parameter to hold a series of values that I want to split on whitespace.