# Disable Forever Node.js Caching

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever

Node.js keeps on using a cached version of my website. I updated the code and even used the `-w` option, but Forever keeps on referring to the cache. How do I disable caching with Forever Node.js and also how do I completely uninstall it?

According to this answer, it does cache:
https://serverfault.com/questions/320973/does-the-forever-daemon-cache-the-node-js-script

Edit:
It seems that this is a persistent issue with Forever:
https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/issues/590

Comment: Are you sure Forever is the culprit?  What happens when you start up your server just using 'node app.js' (or whatever your entry script is called)?

Comment: what do you mean by cache? can you be more specific about the behavior causing issues?

Comment: @HeadCode when I start the app with `node server.js`, everything works fine. I'm sure Forever is caching it. I ran in this problem yesterday and resolved the issue with the `-w` option, but that isn't working now. No idea why.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Yeah, I tried both `forever stop` `forever restart`. Neither fix the issue.

Comment: You've probably tried this, but do you get anything when you run 'forever list' even after killing forever?

Comment: @HeadCode After killing forever, `forever list` shows that nothing is running.

Comment: Does anyone know a better way than forever to run multiple node.js apps?

Comment: You could always blow away the '.forever' directory in your home directory and see what happens.  Make sure you have caching turned off in your browser as well.

Comment: @Soubriquet If `forever list` is empty, then your script may not have been started by `forever`. You may need to find and kill the persistent `node` process yourself ([with `ps` and `kill`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510673/find-and-kill-a-process-in-one-line-using-bash-and-regex) or Task Manager in Windows). Also note that the caching of code is [managed by `node`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) and can't be disabled. It'll keep in memory the result of each file it evaluates until the process is terminated.

Comment: @HeadCode I just tried your suggestion and then reinstalled forever, but the issue is persisting.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I also tried that and nothing changed. :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's still actual but restarting `forever` will help.