# With Jekyll, how do I stop a detached server process from the command line?

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to write a script that launches Jekyll from the command line, does another process, and then stops it.

The logic would be like this:

1. start jekyll serve.
2. run a process called Prince to build a PDF from the HTML files.
3. stop the jekyll server.

I'm not very experienced with the command line. I think I have to use the `--detach` command with Jekyll to continue running scripts after the preview server builds. But then if I detach Jekyll, the only way to stop the server is by killing a specific PID, but the PID number seems to be generated randomly.

Anyone have any tips on how to construct this script?

Comment: Cannot you just do `jekyll build` instead of `jekyll serve` ?

Comment: after i run `jekyll serve`, i need to run princexml, which will look for a collection of html pages to consolidate into a PDF. princexml seems to require the html pages to be crawlable, so if the site is not available at the preview link (http://127.0.0.1/), prince has trouble finding the pages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't know the PID, you can do :

```
kill $(ps aux | grep '[j]ekyll' | awk '{print $2}')
```

See [explanations here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510673/find-and-kill-a-process-in-one-line-using-bash-and-regex)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not quite working. The problem is that as soon as the server detaches, it can't proceed to the next command. Instead I get this message:

```
tjohnson-mbpr13:acme tjohnson$ E, [2015-04-23T17:01:08.179397 #85057] ERROR -- : Couldn't cleanly terminate all actors in 10 seconds!
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but every time I hit the Return key, the site activates the Add Comment button, and doesn't allow me to add any paragraph spacing.

Comment: I had to add the -9 flag to get this to work: `kill -9 $(ps aux | grep '[j]ekyll' | awk '{print $2}') `

Answer (score 0):

Another way to stop the Jekyll process (without PID)

```
pkill -f jekyll
```

Answer (score -1):

In OS X, you can issue

```
killall jekyll
```

I put this into a grunt-shell task. The remaining issue is that neither kill nor killall seem to have a --quiet setting. If it would run with no return code or message, then that shell:jekyllStop grunt task could be the first step in my default. If jekyll happens not to be running, default stops/fails. You can get grunt to continue using --force, but that argument would apply to all tasks.

```
shell: {
  jekyllStop: {
    command: "killall jekyll"
  }
},
```

Running "shell:jekyllStop" (shell) task
No matching processes belonging to you were found
Warning: Command failed: No matching processes belonging to you were found
 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Process finished with exit code 6