# Stop running PHP server, command line

Tags: php, command-line, localhost

So I've done `php -S localhost:8000`, but I don't need it anymore, I need my 8000 localhost back. How to stop the php server?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
PHP 5.4.0 Development Server started at Thu Jul 21 10:43:28 2011
Listening on localhost:8000
Document root is /home/me/public_html
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

If you don't have that terminal open, you have to find the `PID` of the process and kill that.

To find the `PID` and kill the process, [here is a nice explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510673/find-and-kill-a-process-in-one-line-using-bash-and-regex).

Answer (score 28):

`killall -9 php`

That's how I would do it!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to close the terminal window as we cannot type anything while the server is running!

Press the (X) button on the top right(on Windows/Linux)/Press the red color circle on the top left(on Mac OS) of the terminal window to stop the PHP server from running.

To verify, reload the server page and you will find a server not reachable page in place of your server page.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can either close the terminal window or press CTRL C