# How to restart flask app on ubuntu using console command?

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I started a flask app on an ubuntu server over ssh and the internet unfortunatly went down. The flask app however, kept running. Normally you would just press ctrl + C to end the app but I had to start a new window so I'm not at that screen.

I want to restart the app to use the new code changes that I pulled from a repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some options you may use:

1. Casual way: find your flask app `pid` in `ps aux` and put it in command `kill <pid>`
2. Better looking way:  `kill $(ps aux | grep '<your flask-app>' | awk '{print $2}')` for datails, see an answer: [Find and kill a process in one line using bash and regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510673/find-and-kill-a-process-in-one-line-using-bash-and-regex)

If you want to get previous state of the screen on server (to use ctrl-C). Try to use `tmux`. It saves screen state of your session despite on authenticated you or not. `tmux new` – generate new session. `tmux attach` – returning your previous session.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.

Comment: Also found out that you can restart the apache server, it has the same desired effect.