# BASH. Make the result of one command to be an argument of another

Tags: linux, bash, process, parameter-passing

How can I make the result of one command to be an argument of another? 
I'm trying to kill child process by pid of parent process and use for it pgrep

Example: `pgrep -P <PID>`

**But after I need to kill the PID which I get from pgrep**

`pgrep -P <PID> | kill`  - it doesn't work(

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
VALUE="$(pgrep -P <PID>)"
kill ${VALUE}
```

Comment: Yes but I don't want to create env var

Comment: See this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510673/find-and-kill-a-process-in-one-line-using-bash-and-regex) or do what @Kavli suggested below.

Comment: @Avrel It's not an environment variable unless you `export` it, but you can easily combine these two lines anyway.

Answer (score 1):

With single `pkill` command:

```
pkill -P <PID> --signal SIGTERM
```

---

> **`--signal`** *signal*
>                 Defines the signal to send to each matched process.  Either the numeric or the  symbolic  signal  name  can  be
>                 used.  (**`pkill`** only.)

Answer (score 0):

You use backticks for that. Like this:

```
kill `pgrep -P <PID>`
```

Comment: `$( )` is the preferred syntax.

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you

```
kill -9 `command`
```

and as far as getting the pid is concerned see examples below

```
kill -9 `pgrep executable`
kill -9 `pgrep ps`
kill -9 `pgrep bash`
```

or your command

```
kill -9 `pgrep -P <PID>`
```

Comment: You should **never start with `kill -9`**, since it won't allow the process to gracefully die (close file descriptors, free resources, etc). Instead, use `kill -INT`, or `kill -TERM` (the same as `kill`). Only as the last resort, use `kill -9`.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want "kill -9" as well:

```
pgrep -P <PID> | xargs -n1 kill -9
```

To test what it is going to do in advance try:

```
pgrep -P <PID> | xargs -n1 echo kill -9
```

Comment: Why would you _probably_ want `kill -9`?

Comment: xargs - that what I wanted