# Linux use grep command

Tags: linux

I know use `ps -ef | grep test| grep -v grep |wc -l` can list the num of process test,and now i plan to list the **test** processes belong to user :**forme**.is this right as below :
 `ps -ef | grep test|grep -x forme| grep -v grep |wc -l`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start, `grep test| grep -v grep` can be replaced with `grep '[t]est'`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510673/find-and-kill-a-process-in-one-line-using-bash-and-regex/3510850#3510850) for an explanation.

Secondly, if you want to limit the processes to a single user, that's what the `-u` option to `ps` is for:

```
ps -fu forme | grep '[t]est' | wc -l
```

And, finally, `grep` *already* has a `-c` option to count lines, so you can ditch the `wc` part of the pipeline:

```
ps -fu forme | grep -c '[t]est'
```

Comment: You can skip `wc -l` with `grep -c [t]est`.