# How to kill a process in bash through terminal

Tags: linux, bash, centos

This might be a very basic question but I couldn't find it anywhere on the internet.
Lets assume I have a file named test with this code

```
echo hello
sleep 10
echo hello
sleep 10
echo hello
sleep 10
```

How would I go about killing that program through another terminal in my server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find and kill a process in one line using bash and regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510673/find-and-kill-a-process-in-one-line-using-bash-and-regex)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the file is test.sh

You can do:

```
ps -x | grep ./test.sh
```

This will show the processes:

```
11164 pts/1    S+     0:00 /usr/bin/bash ./test.sh
and a second process that will be a grep process, you won't be able to kill the process that has the word grep in it because that process completes right away
```

now you can kill the process using the PID:

```
kill 11164
```

Comment: everything worked exsept the kill 11543
I got an output of
-bash: kill: (11543) - No such process
whenever I type kill 11543 my ourput is 
-bash: kill: (11543) - No such process

Comment: @slimy try redoing the ps -x | grep ./test.sh command, if it shows the process it should be able to close the process by the PID. When you do the ps -x there will be two PID's one for the grep command and one for the script, you don't want the one with the grep command.

Comment: im getting this error
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ

Comment: @slimy can you show me the output of: ps -x | grep ./test.sh

Comment: 11848 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep ./test.sh

Comment: @slimy that is not the correct process. There should be another one. Do you have #! /usr/bin/bash at the top of your .sh file? The grep process disappears right after it executes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216462/discussion-between-bhristov-and-slimy).

Answer (score 0):

Your script filename is `test`.

So, in another terminal, you can execute `ps aux | grep test`.

Then you can get the PID of `test`, which is located at the second column.

Then, execute `kill -9 <PID>`.

Comment: Im using centos 6.9 as a server and i tryed that but it still didnt work it give me and error                                                                               
                                                     
bash: kill: (11773) - No such process  Their is a file named test.sh and ive done all the steps correctly

Comment: @slimy  Are you sure that `test.sh` hasn't finished yet when you execute `kill`?

Answer (score -1):

```
Ctrl c
```

By Pressing this, you can kill that program from your terminal.
And you can kill this program from your main terminal where you exicute this in first place.

Comment: I know to to press ctrl C and ctrl Z but i need to know how to do it throught the command line