# Why do my shell statements cause blocking? bash -c "ps ax | grep 'tcpdump' | grep -v grep | kill -9 $(awk '{print $1}')"

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am rewriting a function to alternate os.system() in Python to ensure that the output of the process is logged.

```py
    def log_system(self, cmd: str):
        cmd = cmd.rstrip(' ')
        if cmd[-1] == '&' and cmd[-2] != '&':
            cmd = cmd[:-1]
            # Redirects standard error to standard output for logging
            executing = os.popen('bash -c ' + '"' + cmd + '"' + '>/dev/stdout 2>&1 &')
        else:
            executing = os.popen('bash -c ' + '"' + cmd + '"' + '>/dev/stdout 2>&1')
        res = executing.readlines()
        ret = executing.close()
        if len(res) > 0:  # print message if have some content
            msg = ''.join(res)
            if ret is None:  # None means process return successfully
                log.i(msg)  # print stdout
            else:
                log.e(f'cmd execute failed: {cmd}\n' + msg)  # print stderr
```

The original statement works well and it is:

```py
os.system("ps ax | grep 'tcpdump' | grep -v grep | kill `awk '{print $1}'` ")
```

After I use log_system(), the shell script could be:

```bash
bash -c "ps ax | grep 'tcpdump' | grep -v grep | kill `awk '{print $1}'`"
```

But, When I execute the code, it blocks, I don't know what happened.

I use terminal to retry, this script is non-blocking:

```bash
ps ax | grep 'tcpdump' | grep -v grep | kill `awk '{print $1}'`
```

and this is also blocking:

```bash
bash -c "ps ax | grep 'tcpdump' | grep -v grep | kill -9 $(awk '{print $1}')"
bash -c "ps ax | grep 'tcpdump' | grep -v grep | kill `awk '{print $1}'`"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `kill` command does not take process IDs on standard input, it must be supplied as an argument.

Specifically, your current command snippet (regardless of what goes into the `kill` standard input) will hang forever because the `awk` is waiting on *its* standard input (the terminal), effectively:

```bash
kill `awk '{print $1}'`
```

Hence the command would need to be something like:

```bash
kill $(ps ax | grep 'tcpdump' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}')
```

with the `$()` capturing the standard output of its content and using that as a command line argument to `kill`.

---

However, you may also want to look at [one of my earlier answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510673/find-and-kill-a-process-in-one-line-using-bash-and-regex/3510850#3510850). There are better tools available for finding and/or killing processes, such as `pgrep` and `pkill`. If you have those available to you, they're usually a better option than trying to do it with `ps/grep/awk` pipelines.

Comment: Thanks! I try this code below and it works well.
```shell
bash -c "kill  $(ps ax | grep '[t]cpdump' |awk '{print $1}')"
```
However, I still want to know what is the difference between the following two snippets:
```shell
ps ax | grep '[t]cpdump' | kill `awk '{print $1}'`  # which is non-blocking
bash -c "ps ax | grep '[t]cpdump' | kill `awk '{print $1}'`"  # which is blocking

Comment: This is shell-dependent. If you run `cmd1 | cmd2 $(cmd3)` in either bash or dash, both `cmd2` and `cmd3` read from the pipe. But in zsh, only `cmd2` reads from the pipe (`cmd3` is essentially outside of the pipeline, and reads fom the terminal or whatever). However, the replacement suggested here should work in any sh-family shell.