# Shell script to capture Process ID and kill it if exist

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I tried this code and it is not working

```
#!/bin/sh

#Find the Process ID for syncapp running instance

PID=`ps -ef | grep syncapp 'awk {print $2}'`

if [[ -z "$PID" ]] then
Kill -9 PID
fi
```

It is showing a error near awk.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Why not just use `killall syncapp` ?

Comment: What if there is no process running? Does it give any error?

Comment: See: [man killall](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall)

Comment: This process of killing is not helping me. Can you suggest how to repair the above method. Thanks

Comment: PID=`ps -ef | grep syncapp 'awk {print $2}'`

I couldn't able to get the output which is actually process id into PID variable.

Is there any syntax wrong or script wrongly written in this line of code.

Comment: On Linux and some other systems, `killall` is definitely the way to go, but be aware that on certain systems (Solaris for one), `killall` is completely different and basically means "ignore any arguments I was given and really kill everything"...

Comment: See also [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510673/find-and-kill-a-process-in-one-line-using-bash-and-regex)

Comment: best way to check if process exists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043978/how-to-check-if-a-process-id-pid-exists

Comment: pgrep processname && pkill processname || echo "Process not running"

Comment: @chandank Echo will also execute if `pkill` fails.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Actually the easiest way to do that would be to pass kill arguments like below:

```
ps -ef | grep your_process_name | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

Comment: `grep "your_process" | awk '{print $2}'` can be simplified to just `awk '/your_process/{print $2}'`

Comment: This runs the (small)  risk of killing the `grep` process before it kills the process you want to kill. To remedy that, use `awk  '/[y]our_process/{print $2}' | xargs kill`, but using `killall` is better.

Comment: This might give problem because ps -ef might also give  "grep --color=auto". So use `ps -ef | grep "your_process" | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v 'grep' | xargs kill`

Comment: Didn't work for me, but if it's tweaked a bit: `kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep "your process" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')` it works like a charm ;)

Comment: All the comments after @reinerpost's are going in precisely the wrong direction. This is a common antipattern; the proper solution is to use a regex which doesn't match itself, and using Awk means you can and should avoid `grep` because Awk can do everything `grep` can do without a separate process, which could be quite significant for a tool you will need to run in situations where the system is starved for memory, processes, or CPU.

Comment: As an aside, `kill -9` is also an antipattern.  Killing a process happens with just `kill` and adding the `-9` is a violent and desperate measure which should always be avoided unless you know for a fact that the process you are trying to kill is buggy (and even then try without the `-9` first).

Comment: you have to exclude both the running grep process and your own process. I put the command in a script and excludes both like this: ` ps -ef | grep "$1" |  grep -v 'grep' | grep -v "$0" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill `

Answer (score 24):

This works good for me.

```
PID=`ps -eaf | grep syncapp | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
if [[ "" !=  "$PID" ]]; then
  echo "killing $PID"
  kill -9 $PID
fi
```

Comment: This works fine as long as only one instance of the process is being executed. But, what if two or more instances of the process were running?

Comment: kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec] ,  not work

Comment: ah sorry i typo, its work..

Answer (score 16):

I use the command `pkill` for this:

```
NAME
       pgrep, pkill - look up or signal processes based on name and 
       other attributes

SYNOPSIS
       pgrep [options] pattern
       pkill [options] pattern

DESCRIPTION
       pgrep looks through the currently running processes and lists 
       the process IDs which match the selection criteria to stdout.
       All the criteria have to match.  For example,

              $ pgrep -u root sshd

       will only list the processes called sshd AND owned by root.
       On the other hand,

              $ pgrep -u root,daemon

       will list the processes owned by root OR daemon.

       pkill will send the specified signal (by default SIGTERM) 
       to each process instead of listing them on stdout.
```

If your code runs via interpreter (java, python, ...) then the name of the process is the name of the interpreter. You need to user the argument --full. This matches against the command name and the arguments.

Comment: super simple and works. I had to do "sudo pkill -9 coreaudiod" for it to work

Comment: Just a note, I had a Java process I wanted to kill, but the **--full** option did not exist for my version of pkill, however **-f** worked as expected, this was on CentOS 6.4.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Read the man page properly and you'll find plenty of useful options -U which restricts to specific users etc.

Answer (score 5):

You probably wanted to write

```
`ps -ef | grep syncapp | awk '{print $2}'`
```

but I will endorse @PaulR's answer - `killall -9 syncapp` is a much better alternative.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find the process name exactly. I'm getting the processes by using grep "sym". sym is the script name which start the process. So it is better for me to use the above method to kill the process.

Comment: PID=ps -ef | grep syncapp 'awk {print $2}' I couldn't able to get the output which is actually process id into PID variable. Is there any syntax wrong or script wrongly written in this line of code.

Comment: @user1597811: What you wrote is very different from what I wrote :p Check where all the quotes, and where all the pipe symbols (`|`) are.

Answer (score 2):

This should kill all processes matching the grep that you are permitted to kill.

*-9 means "Kill all processes you can kill".*

```
kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep [s]yncapp | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: No, `-9` means send signal 9 instead of the regular 15. The precise semantics are that this untrappable signal terminates the process without giving it the chance of running any cleanup code, which is often set up via a signal handler which runs on a *trappable* signal.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of *NIX systems also have either or both [pkill(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) and [killall(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall) which, allows you to kill processes by name. Using them, you can avoid the whole parsing `ps` problem.

Comment: That doesn't work if a process is running under java. I can't use 'killall glassfish' for exemple. I need to use killall java, but it would kill all programs running under java.

Comment: For java processes, you can parse the value from jps and use kill the java process  
`jps | grep "Process Name" | cut -d " " -f "1" | xargs kill -KILL`

Comment: If your code runs via interpreter (java, python, ...) then the name of the process is the name of the interpreter. You need to user the argument `--full`. This matches against the command name and the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Came across somewhere..thought it is simple and useful

You can use the command in crontab directly ,

```
* * * * * ps -lf | grep "user" |  perl -ane '($h,$m,$s) = split /:/,$F
+[13]; kill 9, $F[3] if ($h > 1);'
```

or, we can write it as shell script ,

```
#!/bin/sh
# longprockill.sh
ps -lf | grep "user" |  perl -ane '($h,$m,$s) = split /:/,$F[13]; kill
+ 9, $F[3] if ($h > 1);'
```

And call it crontab like so,

```
* * * * * longprockill.sh
```

Comment: Using `grep | perl` is a novel [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) -- of course Perl already knows how to do `next unless /regex/;` before the part which attempts to parse the input line.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

#Find the Process ID for syncapp running instance

PID=`ps -ef | grep syncapp 'awk {print $2}'`

if [[ -z "$PID" ]] then
--->    Kill -9 PID
fi
```

Not sure if this helps, but 'kill' is not spelled correctly.
It's capitalized.

Try 'kill' instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Kill -9 PID
```

should be

```
kill -9 $PID
```

see the difference?

Answer (score -1):

Try the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
pgrep $1 2>&1 > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
{
    echo " "$1" PROCESS RUNNING "
    ps -ef | grep $1 | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'| xargs kill -9
}
else
{
    echo "  NO $1 PROCESS RUNNING"
};fi
```

Answer (score -2):

```
PID=`ps -ef | grep syncapp 'awk {print $2}'`

if [[ -z "$PID" ]] then
**Kill -9 $PID**
fi
```