# How do I stop the previous command in a bash script?

Tags: node.js, bash

I'm trying to build a bash script that runs unit tests on a web server.

I wish to run a simple bash script that could be (for example) in a makefile that does the following:

1. Start a web server
2. Run the unit tests
3. Stop the web server

Assuming that the web server is written for NodeJS, here's what it could look like:

```
npm start &
sleep 5
npm test
```

The issue with this approach is that the web server will keep on running. How do I stop it after the `npm test` stage?

Comment: Have you considered a `killall`?

Comment: Not really an option. If I understand correctly, `killall` kills all processed that match a keyword you specify. If that's correct, trying to kill my background process would possibly kill others that I wish to leave untouched. Please correct me if that's not what `killall` does :)

Comment: That is exactly what `killall` does. As long as this is the only instance of npm running, one should be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PID of the last started background process is stored in $!, so pick it up after starting npm and kill it when needed:

```
npm start &
npm_pid=$!
...
kill $npm_pid
```

Comment: You want `$!` maybe?

Comment: @andlrc: Ouch, of course, thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't have found the other question if I had looked at the title, but I completely understand the duplicate flag. Either way, many thanks for the answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

You might consider running the process in a screen.

```
screen -dmS npm npm start #Starts a detached screen named npm, and runs "npm start" inside
```

Later, when you need to kill the process, you can just kill the screen. When the screen dies, it will take it's child processes with it.

```
screen -X -S npm quit
```

Comment: Completely different than what I expected. I'm going to read up on `screens`. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a duplicate of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910087/shell-script-to-capture-process-id-and-kill-it-if-exist)

```
ps -ef | grep your_process_name | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill)
```

Comment: Don't c/p another answer from StackOverflow, mark as duplicate instead.