# How to run command CTRL+Z in Shell?

Tags: node.js, linux, shell, ubuntu

I have a Node progress. I want to auto-start it and keep it in background via a shell script. The way I keep background progress is press <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> after run `npm run start`, then run `bg && disown`. Now I've got a problem: How to process this <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> command in Shell script?

Comment: you mean to `kill` the process? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910087/shell-script-to-capture-process-id-and-kill-it-if-exist)

Comment: @Mashiro How about using an existing init system (e.g. SysV init, systemd, etc.) instead of writing your own?

Comment: A supervisor may be useful, you could give a try to https://immortal.run/ `immortal your-command`

Comment: A useful reference on what you're actually doing here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and.  FWIW, if you want to run it as a service, it's much better to use something like systemd (http://nodesource.com/blog/running-your-node-js-app-with-systemd-part-1/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to run a script in the background is to simple write:

```
npm run start &
```

The ampersand starts the process up in the background and makes it so you don't have to worry about processing ctrl-z. If you were dead set on using ctrl-z however, this is actually just a SIGTSTP interrupt and

```
kill -SIGTSTP [PID]
```

could be used to emulate it.