# Killing all the processes bash scripts generated using script names

Tags: bash, process, kill

How can I kill all the processes that a shell script has generated? `myscript` was run several times and created unwanted processes and I want to kill them. I am running an Ubuntu 20.

```
123  sh /usr/local/bin/myscript /mnt/local/data_file/data1.txt
312  sh /usr/local/bin/myscript /mnt/local/data_file/data1.txt
452  sh /usr/local/bin/myscript /mnt/local/data_file/data1.txt
455  sh /usr/local/bin/myscript /mnt/local/data_file/data1.txt
1329 sh /usr/local/bin/myscript /mnt/local/data_file/data1.txt
```

I have tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15896729/1227860), and it does not kill them. Could someone kindly help me find an automated way of finding the processes and kill them all?

Comment: Are you trying to do this just once (in which case `kill 123 312 452 455 1329` should work), or are you trying to automate the process cleanup? If the latter, what exactly are you running (note: I recommend the variant in reinierpost's comment), and what exactly happens (e.g. do you get any error messages, etc)?

Comment: Also, killing a parent process will kill all its child processes UNLESS those child processes were run with the `nohup` command - could those be the ones that are “not working”?  If so, no easy answer other than recursion I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided details, you can kill them using the `pkill --full` or simply `pkill -f`:

```
pkill -f "sh /usr/local/bin/myscript"
```

Optionally use `pgrep -f` against it first to see the matches.