# How to test if a process exists in Bash?

Tags: shell, process, bash

I want to make sure `node` is running when logging in. So in my `.bashrc` file I have:

```
pkill node
sleep 1
node server.js &
```

Of course, that doesn't check if `node` is running... it simply kills it and starts it up again. Instead I'd like something like this:

```
node_process = $(pidof node)
if [not_exists node_process]; then
  node server.js &
fi
```

The problem is the `not_exists` method doesn't seem to exist :). How do I test the existence of a number or string in Bash and is this the best way to ensure node is up and running upon login?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a process id (PID) exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043978/how-to-check-if-a-process-id-pid-exists)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check if a string is empty using `-z`:

```
node_process_id=$(pidof node)
if [[ -z $node_process_id ]]; then
    node server.js &
fi
```

`pidof` returns nothing if no matching processes are found, so `node_process_id` would be set to an empty string.

Comment: This seems like exactly what I'm looking for. Can I just move the `$(pidof node)` inside the `if` condition? Curious why I need 2 square brackets around the `if` condition?

Comment: The double brackets are just a more friendly `bash` version of the single brackets. And yes, I think `if ! pidof node; then node server.js & fi` should work fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, was banging my head to find a clean solution. Works like a charm.