# Check if a program in a specific path is running

Tags: linux, bash, process

I am trying to check if a process is running with the code below:

```
SERVICE="./yowsup/yowsup-cli"
RESULT=`ps aux | grep $SERVICE`

if [ "${RESULT:-null}" = null ]; then
    echo "not running"
else
    echo "running"
fi
```

But it keeps echoing it is running although it is not. I realized that the grep itself comes as a result and that is the issue.

How can I skip the grep and just check for the process?

Comment: By **pid**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043978/how-to-check-if-a-process-id-pid-exists

Comment: By **name**: https://askubuntu.com/questions/157779/how-to-determine-whether-a-process-is-running-or-not-and-make-use-it-to-make-a-c/1317605

Answer (score 14):

Use [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep):

```
if pgrep "$SERVICE" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    echo "$SERVICE is running"
fi
```

or:

```
if pgrep -f "/path/to/$SERVICE" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    echo "$SERVICE is running"
fi
```

**NOTE:**

- `pgrep` interprets its argument as a *regular expression*. As a result, paths containing regex characters will likely fail to match or produce false positives (e.g. `pgrep -f /home/user/projects/c++/application/executable` won't work as expected due to `+`). This issue can be worked around by escaping the characters in question (e.g. `pgrep -f /home/user/projects/c\+\+/application/executable`)
- `pgrep -f <pattern>` matches the specified pattern against the *whole* command line of running processes. As a result, it will match paths appearing as *arguments* of other processes (e.g. run `nano /usr/bin/sleep` in one terminal and `pgrep -f /usr/bin/sleep` in another -> `pgrep` reports the pid of `nano` since it contains `/usr/bin/sleep` as an argument in its command line). To prevent these kind of false positives, prefix the pattern with a caret (`^`) to force `pgrep` to only match against the *beginning* of the command line (e.g. `pgrep -f ^/usr/bin/sleep`)

Comment: This is actually not that reliable as `pgrep` interprets the argument specified as a _pattern_. As a result, paths containing regex characters will fail to match or produce false positives, e.g. `pgrep -f "/home/user/projects/c++/application/executable"` won't work as expected.

Comment: @Maxxim Good point, thanks for the input! ... I know that `grep` has the option `-F` for a fixed string search (no pattern), but pgrep apparently doesn't have this option.

Comment: ps: awk could be used for a fixed string search. Like this: `ps ax -o pid,cmd | awk -v search='search_string' '{pid=$1;$1=""} index($0, search){print pid}'` ... In this example, `search_string` may contain any kind of special character.

Comment: Upon further inspection, I'd say `pgrep -f` is actually not reliable at all and should probably be avoided altogether. Try the following: run `nano /usr/bin/sleep` in one terminal and `pgrep -f /usr/bin/sleep` in another -> `pgrep` will report the pid of `nano` since it contains `/usr/bin/sleep` in its command line. It seems `pgrep -f` blindly matches against the whole command line, including arguments. I'd say this disqualifies `pgrep -f` for this use case entirely.

Comment: @Maxxim It seems you are right, I should remove `-f` from my answer. I will leave that to you if you want?, in the meanwhile your note keeps in sync with the answer. Thanks again, appreciated!

Comment: I opted to add another note as there is a viable workaround. Also, I think it's better to keep a (partially) wrong answer and explain its pitfalls/limitations so others can learn from it. My guess is that if you were to remove it, someone else would probably repost it anyway as `pgrep`'s goofs are not very obvious (took me quite some time to figure it out). I removed the 'more reliable' remark though as that is not necessarily true now that we know more about it.

Answer (score 7):

For systems where `pgrep` isn't available you can use:

```
service="[.]/yowsup/yowsup-cli"

if ps aux | grep -q "$service"; then
    echo "not running"
else
    echo "running"
fi
```

- `[.]` in will force `grep` to not list itself as it won't match `[.]` regex.
- `grep -q` can be utilized to avoid command substitution step.
- Prefer using lowercase variables in shell.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `grep` you call sometimes finds himself in a `ps` list, so it is good only when you check it interactively:

```
$ ps -ef | grep bash
...
myaut    19193  2332  0 17:28 pts/11   00:00:00 /bin/bash
myaut    19853 15963  0 19:10 pts/6    00:00:00 grep --color=auto bash
```

Easiest way to get it is to use [`pidof`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof). It accepts both full path and executable name:

```
service="./yowsup/yowsup-cli" # or service="yowsup-cli"
if pidof "$service" >/dev/null; then
    echo "not running"
else
    echo "running"
fi
```

There is more powerful version of `pidof` -- [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep).

---

However, if you start your program from a script, you may save it's PID to a file:

```
service="./yowsup/yowsup-cli"
pidfile="./yowsup/yowsup-cli.pid"
service &
pid=$!
echo $pid > $pidfile
```

And then check it with [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep):

```
if pgrep -F "$pidfile" >/dev/null; then
    echo "not running"
else
    echo "running"
fi
```

This is common technique in `/etc/init.d` start scripts.

Answer (score 2):

**The following solution avoids issues with `ps` + `grep`, `pgrep` and `pidof` (see *Advantages* below):**

```
# Check if process is running [$1: path to executable]
function is_process_running() {
    local path="$1" line
    while read -r line; do
        [[ "${line}" == "${path}" || "${line}" == "${path} "* ]] && return 0
    done < <(ps -e -o command=)
    return 1
}

is_process_running "./yowsup/yowsup-cli" && echo "running" || echo "not running"
```

**Explanation:**

- `ps -e -o command=` list all processes, only output command line of each process, omit header line
- `while read -r line; do ... done < <(ps ...)` process output produced by `ps` line by line
- `[[ "${line}" == "${path}" || "${line}" == "${path} "* ]]` check if line matches path exactly -or- path + space + argument(s)

**Advantages:**

- Works for paths containing regex special characters that would trip `grep` without option `-F` or `pgrep`, e.g. `/home/user/projects/c++/application/executable` (see ***NOTE*** in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29260629/1976617) for details)
- Avoids issues with `ps` + `grep` / `pgrep` reporting false positives if path appears as argument of some other process (e.g. `nano /usr/bin/sleep` + `pgrep -f /usr/bin/sleep` -> falsely reports pid of `nano` process)
- Avoids issues with `pidof` reporting false positives for processes that are run from `PATH` (e.g. `sleep 60s &` + `pidof /tmp/sleep` -> falsely reports pid of `sleep` process running from `/usr/bin/sleep`, regardless of whether `/tmp/sleep` actually exists or not)

Answer (score 1):

I thought [pidof](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof) was made for this.

```
function isrunning()
{
    pidof -s "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1
    status=$?
    if [[ "$status" -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo 1
    else
        echo 0
    fi
)
if [[ $(isrunning bash) -eq 1 ]]; then echo "bash is running"; fi
if [[ $(isrunning foo) -eq 1 ]]; then echo "foo is running"; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
## bash

## function to check if a process is alive and running:

_isRunning() {
    ps -o comm= -C "$1" 2>/dev/null | grep -x "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1
}

## example 1: checking if "gedit" is running

if _isRunning gedit; then
    echo "gedit is running"
else
    echo "gedit is not running"
fi

## example 2: start lxpanel if it is not there

if ! _isRunning lxpanel; then
    lxpanel &
fi

## or

_isRunning lxpanel || (lxpanel &)
```

---

**Note**: `pgrep -x lxpanel` or `pidof lxpanel` still reports that `lxpanel` is running even when it is defunct (zombie); so to get alive-and-running process, we need to use `ps` and `grep`

Answer (score 0):

```
current_pid="$$" # get current pid
# Looking for current pid. Don't save lines either grep or current_pid
isRunning=$(ps -fea | grep -i $current_pid | grep -v -e grep -e $current_pid)

# Check if this script is running
if [[ -n "$isRunning" ]]; then
    echo "This script is already running."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SERVICE="./yowsup/yowsup-cli"
RESULT=`ps aux | grep $SERVICE|grep -v grep`

if [ "${RESULT:-null}" = null ]; then
    echo "not running"
else
    echo "running"
fi
```

Comment: Please share more details such that others can learn from it

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).