# Determining through Shell Script if a Linux process is running with given arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

The company I work to has a crontab set to run a given Shell Script every few minutes to perform certain complex operations without the users' intervention. This script basically executes multiple Perl scripts in a sequence, checking first if they are not running already, using the following structure as many times as there are customers:

```
for i in `seq 1 20`;
do
    ps ax | grep ourFile10000008.p | grep pl 2>> /dev/null >> $LOG
    if [ $? -eq 1 ] ; then
        cd /path/to/the/script
        perl ourFile10000008.pl 10000008 & 2>> $LOG
    fi
    ps ax | grep ourFile10000009.p | grep pl 2>> /dev/null >> $LOG

    if [ $? -eq 1 ] ; then
        cd /path/to/the/script
        perl ourFile10000009.pl 10000009 & 2>> $LOG
    fi
    # (and so on, and so forth...)
done
```

This kind of works, except for the fact that there are now dozens of "ourFile" Perl script in our `/path/to/the/script` folder, and they are exact copies of each other! Every time a new customer comes online, we need to create a new replica, which makes maintaining this structure very hard to say the least.

I'm trying to make this structure run on a single file (named here as [theOneFile.pl]) that's another copy of those scripts but is called every time with a new argument. This works, but now I have to make sure I'm only running this file once per argument passed.

After some research, and thanks to [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29260629/8190477), I have successfully determined the argument behind a running [theOneFile.pl] through `pgrep -af theOneFile.pl | tr '\000' ' '| awk '{print $4}' >> $LOG`. However, this gives me a list of results to content with. To keep today's logic as intact as possible, I'm trying to determine only if there is one of these processes running with one specific argument at that given time (eg. theOneFile.pl 10000009), but I'm not sure how to do so. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pgref -f` (which you are using) does match the pattern to the whole command line of a process, not just the process name. That said, you can use:

```
arg="foo"
pgrep -f "theOneFile.pl.*${arg}"
```

Well, the `pgrep` approach is prone to race conditions. Better would be to to change the script itself to use an [exclusive lock](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html) - per argument.