# How to find if process is running or not?

Tags: linux, process, grep, rhel, ps

I have created the following bash script to find out if process is running or not

```
ps -ef | grep process_name 
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Process is running."
else
  echo "Process is not running."
fi
```

However, the script is always returning `"Process is running."`

Please suggest the correct way to find out if the process is running or not.

Comment: [How to determine whether a process is running or not and make use it to make a conditional shell script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/157779), [Check if a process is running using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29260576/608639), [Bash script to check running process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2903354/608639), [Linux Script to check if process is running and act on the result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20162678/608639), etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a process is running using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260576/check-if-a-process-is-running-using-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PR=$(ps -ef | grep process_name | wc -l) 
if [ "$PR" -ge 2 ]; then
    echo "Process is running."
else
    echo "Process is not running."
fi
```

first line, always has the output including the `grep process_name` its self. so running process comes at second line.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `grep process_name` on your process list. So makes sure it is omitted :)

```
ps -ef | grep -v "grep process_name" | grep process_name
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Process is running."
else
  echo "Process is not running."
fi
```