# How to check if ssh-agent is already running in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have a sample `sh` script on my Linux environment, which basically run's the `ssh-agent` for the current shell, adds a key to it and runs two git commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add /home/duvdevan/.ssh/id_rsa

git -C /var/www/duvdevan/ reset --hard origin/master
git -C /var/www/duvdevan/ pull origin master
```

Script actually works fine, but every time I run it I get a new process so I think it might become a performance issue and I might end up having useless processes out there.

An example of the output:

```
Agent pid 12109
Identity added: /home/duvdevan/.ssh/custom_rsa (rsa w/o comment)
```

Also, along with all this, is it possible to find an existing `ssh-agent` process and add my keys into it?

Comment: Try `$SSH_AGENT_PID`.

Comment: If you want to kill a process after spawning it, you can store its PID into a variable and call it like so: `kill -9 $PID_SSH_AGENT`

Comment: I think making the script responsible for starting an agent is the wrong approach. Just assume that an agent *is* running, and require any user to ensure that they have an agent already (usually started by your initial login shell.)

Comment: You could also simply run such a script with `ssh-agent my-script` to start an agent that exits as soon as `my-script` exits.

Comment: I cannot do that since login to the machine multiple times a day - and not just me, but other people as well.

Comment: Kill the agent when you logout, or use agent-forwarding to only run the agent on your local machine if you are ssh-ing into the machine.

Comment: if you kill the agent process and if the bash session is still open, the variable $SSH_AGENT_PID still holds the pid information. make sure to clear this variable after killing the process.

Comment: Another variant would be to check if there are any agent processes running via `ps aux | grep ssh-agent`. If you pipe this further to `| wc -l` and this equals "0", there are no running processes anymore.

Comment: ps -p $SSH_AGENT_PID > /dev/null || eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

Comment: _You'd think the agent itself will have a built-in option to only run a new process if not already running... **but no, we have to write some complex scripts!**_

Answer (score 65, accepted):

> Also, along with all this, is it possible to find an existing ssh-agent process and add my keys into it?

Yes. We can store the connection info in a file:

```
# Ensure agent is running
ssh-add -l &>/dev/null
if [ "$?" == 2 ]; then
    # Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

    # Load stored agent connection info.
    test -r ~/.ssh-agent && \
        eval "$(<~/.ssh-agent)" >/dev/null

    ssh-add -l &>/dev/null
    if [ "$?" == 2 ]; then
        # Start agent and store agent connection info.
        (umask 066; ssh-agent > ~/.ssh-agent)
        eval "$(<~/.ssh-agent)" >/dev/null
    fi
fi

# Load identities
ssh-add -l &>/dev/null
if [ "$?" == 1 ]; then
    # The agent has no identities.
    # Time to add one.
    ssh-add -t 4h
fi
```

This code is from [pitfalls of ssh agents](http://rabexc.org/posts/pitfalls-of-ssh-agents) which describes both the pitfalls of what you're currently doing, of this approach, and how you should use [ssh-ident](https://github.com/ccontavalli/ssh-ident) to do this for you.

---

If you only want to run ssh-agent if it's not running and do nothing otherwise:

```
if [ $(ps ax | grep [s]sh-agent | wc -l) -gt 0 ] ; then
    echo "ssh-agent is already running"
else
    eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    if [ "$(ssh-add -l)" == "The agent has no identities." ] ; then
        ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    fi

    # Don't leave extra agents around: kill it on exit. You may not want this part.
    trap "ssh-agent -k" exit
fi
```

However, this doesn't ensure `ssh-agent` will be accessible (just because it's running doesn't mean we have `$SSH_AGENT_PID` for `ssh-add` to connect to).

Comment: **This should be the accepted answer.**  At least the first half, because `ssh-add -l` is the right way to test for a live agent ([I'd rather suggest `timeout 0.3 ssh-add -l`](https://gist.github.com/hilbix/7d3bacb1b91cdf6df5c6) because `ssh-add` can hang on starved `ssh`-connections - i.E. in `tmux`).  Your first script works on KDE or remote sessions with `ssh -A`.  However the second half is more or less useless like all the other answers here, as often there is no `ssh-agent` running locally.  BTW: Why the `[s]` in `grep [s]sh-agent` and not `grep -F ssh-agent` (which spares some cycles).

Comment: "as often there is no ssh-agent running locally" -- except in OP's case where their problem was multiple ssh-agents. "Why the [s]" -- `ps ax|grep -F ssh-agent` will return the grep process because ps output includes program arguments (try it). Using the character class in the regex will prevent grep from matching itself. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/9375940/79125

Comment: This is also a cool answer because it tells "how to tell that ssh-agent is dead" or "how to figure out whether ssh-agent is running without knowing the pid". Makes sense when one has `screen` or `tmux` in conjunction with agent forwarding.

Comment: I never considered doing an `eval "$(<~/.ssh-agent)"` and would rather `source ~/.ssh-agent`. Just curious if it makes any difference.

Comment: @chutz: eval is suggested by the ssh-agent docs (likely because they don't use an intermediate file), but I'm not sure if there's a difference. That might make a good question (closest I found was [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/174721/9411)).

Comment: my one-liner in zsh: `if [[ $(ssh-add -l &>/dev/null)? -eq 2 ]] ; then eval $(ssh-agent); fi`

Answer (score 80):

## No, really, how to check if `ssh-agent` is already running in bash?

Answers so far don't appear to answer the original question...

Here's what works for me:

```
if ps -p $SSH_AGENT_PID > /dev/null
then
   echo "ssh-agent is already running"
   # Do something knowing the pid exists, i.e. the process with $PID is running
else
eval `ssh-agent -s`
fi
```

**[This was taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15774758)**

Comment: **Usually does not work**.  Neither in graphical sessions (where `ssh-agent` runs locally or is built into the key manager) or session with `ssh -A`, where the `ssh-agent` runs locally.  The correct way can be found in [the answer of idbrii](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48509425/490291)

Comment: Can confirm `SSH_AGENT_PID` is unreliable. On my Mac (High Sierra) and SSH `OpenSSH_7.8p1`, when invoking ssh connection directly, e.g. `ssh host`, the agent is started with `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` but **not** `SSH_AGENT_PID`

Comment: @AlexanderKucheryuk is right. On Mac M1 on Ventura, this is the case for me. `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is always set but `SSH_AGENT_PID` is always empty or missing. Downvoted the answer as a result.

Answer (score 11):

`ps -p $SSH_AGENT_PID > /dev/null || eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`

Single line command. Run for the first time will start ssh-agent. Run for the second time will not start the ssh-agent. Simple and Elegant Mate !!!

Comment: Not bullet proof but quite elegant solution :)

Comment: In some systems you might get a warning if `$SSH_AGENT_PID` is not set. Also you will get a message after running `eval ssh-agent -s`. I modified the above to make it completely silent:
`ps -p "000$SSH_AGENT_PID" > /dev/null || eval "$(ssh-agent -s) > /dev/null"`

Answer (score 10):

If you want it to be killed right after the script exits, you can just add this after the eval line:

```
trap "kill $SSH_AGENT_PID" exit
```

Or:

```
trap "ssh-agent -k" exit
```

`$SSH_AGENT_PID` gets set in the eval of `ssh-agent -s`.

You should be able to find running `ssh-agent`s by scanning through `/tmp/ssh-*` and reconstruct the `SSH_AGENT` variables from it (`SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `SSH_AGENT_PID`).

Comment: Why shouldn't I just add `kill -9 $SSH_AGENT_PID` at the end of my script, as @alok said in his comment on the question?

Comment: If the script itself gets killed (with an interruptable signal) while running, that command won't be run. With the trap it will.

Comment: Also, `kill -9` should never be necessary except for killing a bugging program during development. `kill` by itself should be sufficient in almost every instance.

Comment: Yes. I've just seen that `ssh-agent -k` kills the process and unsets `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `SSH_AGENT_PID` variables - I'm using your solution with `trap`. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Using `$SSH_AGENT_PID` can only test the `ssh-agent` but miss identities when it is not yet added

```
$ eval `ssh-agent`
Agent pid 9906
$ echo $SSH_AGENT_PID
9906
$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

So it would be save to check it with `ssh-add -l` with an [expect script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository/56304600#56304600) like example below:

```
$ eval `ssh-agent -k`
Agent pid 9906 killed
$ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
$ ssh-add -l &>/dev/null
$ [[ "$?" == 2 ]] && eval `ssh-agent`
Agent pid 9547
$ ssh-add -l &>/dev/null
$ [[ "$?" == 1 ]] && expect $HOME/.ssh/agent
spawn ssh-add /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa)
$ ssh-add -l
4096 SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

So when both `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add -l` are put to run on a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh-add -l &>/dev/null
[[ "$?" == 2 ]] && eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add -l &>/dev/null
[[ "$?" == 1 ]] && expect $HOME/.ssh/agent
```

then it would always check and assuring that the connection is running:

```
$ ssh-add -l
4096 SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

You can also emulate the repeating of commands on above script with [do while](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57776266/4058484)

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer did not work for me under Ubuntu 14.04.

The test to check if the ssh-agent is running I have to use is:

```
[[ ! -z ${SSH_AGENT_PID+x} ]]
```

And I am starting the ssh-agent with:

```
exec ssh-agent bash
```

Otherwise the `SSH_AGENT_PID` is not set.

The following seems to work under both Ubuntu 14.04 and 18.04.

```
#!/bin/bash
sshkey=id_rsa
# Check ssh-agent
if [[ ! -z ${SSH_AGENT_PID+x} ]]
then
    echo "[OK] ssh-agent is already running with pid: "${SSH_AGENT_PID}
else
    echo "Starting new ssh-agent..."
    `exec ssh-agent bash`
    echo "Started agent with pid: "${SSH_AGENT_PID}
fi
# Check ssh-key
if [[ $(ssh-add -L | grep ${sshkey} | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]
then
    echo "[OK] SSH key already added to ssh-agent"
else
    echo "Need to add SSH key to ssh-agent..."
    # This should prompt for your passphrase
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/${sshkey}
fi
```

Comment: `SSH_AGENT_PID` is missing on most newer Macs. See my comment on one of answers above.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all the answers here.  I've used this thread a few times over the years to tweak my approach.  Wanted to share my current `ssh-agent.sh` checker/launcher script that works for me on Linux and OSX.

The following block is my `$HOME/.bash.d/ssh-agent.sh`

```
function check_ssh_agent() {
  if [ -f $HOME/.ssh-agent ]; then
    source $HOME/.ssh-agent > /dev/null
  else
    # no agent file
    return 1
  fi

  if [[ ${OSTYPE//[0-9.]/} == 'darwin' ]]; then
    ps -p $SSH_AGENT_PID > /dev/null  
    # gotcha: does not verify the PID is actually an ssh-agent
    # just that the PID is running
    return $?
  fi

  if [ -d /proc/$SSH_AGENT_PID/ ]; then
    # verify PID dir is actually an agent
    grep ssh-agent /proc/$SSH_AGENT_PID/cmdline  > /dev/null  2> /dev/null; 
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      # yep - that is an agent
      return 0
    else
      # nope - that is something else reusing the PID
      return 1
    fi
  else
    # agent PID dir does not exist - dead agent
    return 1
  fi 
}

function launch_ssh_agent() {
  ssh-agent > $HOME/.ssh-agent
  source $HOME/.ssh-agent
  # load up all the pub keys
  for I in $HOME/.ssh/*.pub ; do
    echo adding ${I/.pub/}
    ssh-add ${I/.pub/}
  done
}

check_ssh_agent
if [ $? -eq 1 ];then
  launch_ssh_agent
fi
```

I launch the above from my `.bashrc` using:

```
if [ -d $HOME/.bash.d ]; then
  for I in $HOME/.bash.d/*.sh; do
    source $I  
  done
fi
```

Hope this helps others get up and going quickly.

Created a public gist if you want to hack/improve this with me: https://gist.github.com/dayne/a97a258b487ed4d5e9777b61917f0a72

Answer (score 2):

Regarding finding running ssh-agents, previous answers either don't work or rely on a magic file like `$HOME/.ssh_agent`. These approaches require us to believe that user never run agents without saving their output to this file.

My approach instead relies on a rarely changed default UNIX domain socket template to find an accessible `ssh-agent` among available possibilities.

```sh
# (Paste the below code to your ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc files)
C=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK
R=n/a
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK
for s in $(ls $C /tmp/ssh-*/agent.* 2>/dev/null | sort -u) ; do
  if SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$s ssh-add -l >/dev/null ; then R=$? ; else R=$? ; fi
  case "$R" in
    0|1) export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$s ; break ;;
  esac
done
if ! test -S "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ; then
  eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  unset SSH_AGENT_PID
  R=1
fi
echo "Using $SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
if test "$R" = "1" ; then
  ssh-add
fi
```

In this approach, `SSH_AGENT_PID` remains unknown, since it is hard to deduce it for non-roots. I assume it is actually not required for users since they don't normally want to stop agents. On my system, setting `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is enough to communicate with agent for e.g. passwordless authentication.
The code should work with any shell-compatible shell.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
cat /usr/local/bin/ssh-agent-pro << 'EOF'
#!/usr/bin/env bash
SSH_AUTH_CONST_SOCK="/var/run/ssh-agent.sock"

if [[ x$(wc -w <<< $(pidof ssh-agent)) != x1 ]] || [[ ! -e ${SSH_AUTH_CONST_SOCK} ]]; then
  kill -9 $(pidof ssh-agent) 2>/dev/null
  rm -rf ${SSH_AUTH_CONST_SOCK}
  ssh-agent -s -a ${SSH_AUTH_CONST_SOCK} 1>/dev/null
fi

echo "export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=${SSH_AUTH_CONST_SOCK}"
echo "export SSH_AGENT_PID=$(pidof ssh-agent)"
EOF
echo "eval \$(/usr/local/bin/ssh-agent-pro)" >> /etc/profile
. /etc/profile
```

then you can `ssh-add xxxx` once, you can use ssh-agent everytime when you login.

Comment: @Wang-Zhang Nice `ssh-agent` wrapper. I like it :+1:

Comment: `pidof` is not a builtin command on mac

Answer (score 1):

Very simple command to check how many processes are running for ssh-agent (or any other program): `pidof ssh-agent`
or:
`pgrep ssh-agent`

And very simple command to kill all processes of ssh-agent (or any program):
`kill $(pidof ssh-agent)`

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me (on Mac M1)

Answer (score 1):

On Mac, I had the same issue as the OP, and I had multiple identities set up and when I was running `git push` (even with no local changes) I saw an error message:

```bash
$ git push
ERROR: Write access to repository not granted. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Turns out, the issues that I had were twofold:

1. When I ran `ssh-add -l`, I could see there was an extraneous identity - i.e. one which didn't exist anymore. That is, I thought I deleted it earlier, but it was still registered on `ssh-agent`.
2. I had too many running `ssh-agent` processes (normally there should only be 1-2 running) when I ran `pgrep ssh-agent`.

---

The fix it, the solution was rather simple. First, it is helpful to authorize the SSH key on GitHub.

If using Enterprise Cloud, you might need to
[authorize the SSH key for use with SAML](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/authentication/authenticating-with-saml-single-sign-on/authorizing-an-ssh-key-for-use-with-saml-single-sign-on).

Under [Settings > SSH and GPG keys](https://github.com/settings/keys) on your target GitHub account, find your SSH key and ensure SSO is enabled.

Choose `Configure SSO` and `Authorize` - see image below.

[image: Configure SSO for SSH Key]

Next, to be safe I closed most if not all open terminal windows.

Then to kill all those running `ssh-agent` processes, I ran:

```bash
kill $(pgrep ssh-agent)
```

Then, I started a new window and when it said:

```bash
$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities
```

If `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is unset, you might need to first start up `ssh-agent`. Note tthat I didn't need to run this command myself.

```bash
test -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" && eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

I just add them back with `ssh-add`:

```bash
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_<user>
```

I can confirm that `ssh-add -l` now lists all identities after restarting a new terminal window.

---

If anyone **still** runs into issues, there could be a problem with the clone or push URL for a project. For example, using HTTPS instead of SSH.

Note that `insteadOf` in git config does not chain. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77983896/10237506) (along with its answer) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I made this bash function to count and return the number of running ssh-agent processes... it searches ssh-agent process using procfs instead of using `$ ps -p $SSH_AGENT_PID`:cmd or `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK`:var ... (these ENV-var. can still be set with old values while ssh-agent's process is already killed: if `$ ssh-agent -k` or `$ $(ssh-agent -k)` instead of `$ eval $(ssh-agent -k)`)

```sh
function count_agent_procfs(){
    declare -a agent_list=( ) 
    for folders in $(ls -d /proc/*[[:digit:]] | grep -v /proc/1$);do
        fichier="${folders}/stat"
        pid=${folders/\/proc\//}
        [[ -f ${fichier} ]] && [[ $(cat ${fichier} | cut -d " " -f2) == "(ssh-agent)" ]] && agent_list+=(${pid})
    done
    return ${#agent_list[@]}
}
```

..and then if there is a lot of ssh-agent process running you get their PID with this list...`"${agent_list[@]}"`

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that having a running agent is not enough because sometimes, the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable is set or pointing to a socket file that does not exist anymore.

Therefore, to connect to an already running `ssh-agent` on your machine, you can do this :

```
$ pgrep -u $USER -n ssh-agent -a
1906647 ssh-agent -s
$ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
$ test -z "$SSH_AGENT_PID" && export SSH_AGENT_PID=$(pgrep -u $USER -n ssh-agent)
$ test -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" && export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(ls /tmp/ssh-*/agent.$(($SSH_AGENT_PID-1)))
$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

Comment: This is nice and neat trick that solves the problem to pair agent PID to existing socket!  Best answer here.

Comment: `SSH_AGENT_PID` is not set or missing on newer Macs. see my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from AndrewD was the most helpful for me in most cases, but I found out that when `$SSH_AGENT_PID` is not set or present, the `ps` command will respond with the error:

```
error: list of process IDs must follow -p
```

To fix this, we need to check the existence of the `$SSH_AGENT_PID` variable so that the condition case will now be:

```bash
if [ -n "$SSH_AGENT_PID" ] && ps -p "$SSH_AGENT_PID" > /dev/null
```

The entire modified snippet:

```bash
if [ -n "$SSH_AGENT_PID" ] && ps -p "$SSH_AGENT_PID" > /dev/null
then
   echo "ssh-agent is already running"
   # Do something knowing the pid exists, i.e. the process with $PID is running
else
eval `ssh-agent -s`
fi
```

Shorter and revised version:

```bash
if ! [ -n "$SSH_AGENT_PID" ] || ! ps -p "$SSH_AGENT_PID" > /dev/null
then
    eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
fi

ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_ed25519
```

Answer (score -1):

You can modify line #1 to:

```
PID_SSH_AGENT=`eval ssh-agent -s | grep -Po "(?<=pid\ ).*(?=\;)"`
```

And then at the end of the script you can do:

```
kill -9 $PID_SSH_AGENT
```

Comment: Firstly, $varname references a variable, it can't be set that way. Secondly, why would you want to do that if `eval ssh-agent` already sets $SSH_AGENT_PID?

Comment: Sorry, did not know that it sets that variable. And yes, $ should not have been there. Thanks.