# Reuse in PowerShell a running PuTTY agent (pageant)

Tags: powershell, ssh, putty, pageant

**Is there a way in PS 5.1 to *reuse* the PuTTY agent keys?**

**Now, the details.**

[image]

To use key agents one has an *Agent* that holds the keys (left box), and *Client* Applications that delegate administration of the keys (right box).
E.g., client application C1=`putty` can use its own agent A1=`pageant`, of course.
Client application C2=`winscp` knows how to use directly A1.

Certain Clients cannot use certain Agents directly, but there are Proxy agents that bridge the gap.
For instance to use A1 with C3, I need Proxy P1=`ssh-pageant`, see example below.
This helps centralizing in a single Agent the keys for many Clients.
Now I mean to use A1 for all my Clients (currently, only missing A1-C5 and A1-C6).

**Is there a way in PS 5.1 to *reuse* the same PuTTY agent keys?**
**(I.e., a Proxy Px to use A1 with C5)**

**Possibly helpful**:
https://superuser.com/a/1173570/245595

---

**NOTES**:

1. I did not try it, but it seems like [`winssh-pageant`](https://github.com/ndbeals/winssh-pageant) is a Proxy to link A2 with Client applications that understand A1 directly.
2. I am currently trying to use in PS the same `ssh-pageant` from msys2 (it is a Windows program in the end, and often times they do work), manually replacing what `eval` does in msys2 (so far with no luck, but I think this is fixable):

```
    > cd <dir where ssh-pageant is>
    > .\ssh-pageant -r -a "$env:USERPROFILE\tmp\.ssh-pageant-$env:USERNAME"
    SSH_AUTH_SOCK='C:\Users\USER1\tmp\.ssh-pageant-USER1'; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
    SSH_PAGEANT_PID=714; export SSH_PAGEANT_PID;
    echo ssh-pageant pid 714;
    > $env:SSH_AUTH_SOCK='C:\Users\USER1\tmp\.ssh-pageant-USER1'
    > $env:SSH_PAGEANT_PID=714
    > ssh myserver
    Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\USER1/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

3. As an alternative workaround, **is there a non-admin (I wouldn't want to interfere with it) way to load keys into a separate agent such that when I start a PS session it uses those other keys, and which allows me to keep working with my reused keys in msys2?**
   This would perhaps amount to using a two different agents at the same time...
4. [`weasel-pageant`](https://github.com/vuori/weasel-pageant#thanks-to-all-the-users-over-the-years-and-happy-sshing) is such a proxy agent (based on Cygwin's `ssh-pageant`), for WSL (A1-C7)... still looking for a solution for PS.
5. [`ssh-agent-wsl`](https://github.com/rupor-github/ssh-agent-wsl)
   is a fork of `weasel-pageant` that includes support for using keys held by Microsoft's SSH Agent service (instead of PuTTY Pageant) (A2-C7... I guess it's remarkable that WSL needs a proxy to use Win OpenSSH agent).

---

**Example on how to use "Proxy" agent `ssh-pageant` to link PuTTY pageant with Cygwin bash**

The steps to achieve this are:

1. When I start my session in Windows, the portable PuTTY agent (`pageant`) is executed, loading at the same time one key.
   For this, a shortcut `pageant` is added to `C:\Users\USER1\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`, pointing at `%myputty%\pageant.exe "%mykeys%\key1.ppk"`.

   This makes the key usable by PuTTY and WinSCP, e.g.
   But if I now enter a PS session, or an msys2/cygwin terminal, the keys would not be used, and I am asked for the password for the keys.
   So if I now

```
    $ ssh myserver
    Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\USER1/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

2. In msys2/cygwin I can use [`ssh-pageant`](https://github.com/cuviper/ssh-pageant) ("An SSH authentication agent for Cygwin/MSYS that links OpenSSH to PuTTY's Pageant"), such that it reuses whatever keys a previously loaded PuTTY agent has.

   For this purpose, I simply add `eval $(/usr/bin/ssh-pageant -r -a "/tmp/.ssh-pageant-$USERNAME")` to my `~/.bashrc` of msys2.
   Now whenever I start an msys2 terminal, the link *PuTTY's Pageant* -> *ssh-pageant*  is established, a couple of environment variables are created, and I can `ssh` without entering the password

```
    $ env | grep -i ssh
    SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/.ssh-pageant-USER1
    SSH_PAGEANT_PID=960
    $ ssh myserver
    Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-40-generic x86_64)
    ...
```

3. Judging from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18683544/2707864), it seems the same can be achieved for Git bash.

---

**Related**:

http://rabexc.org/posts/pitfalls-of-ssh-agents

[How to check if ssh-agent is already running in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40549332/how-to-check-if-ssh-agent-is-already-running-in-bash)

https://superuser.com/questions/1327633/how-to-maintain-ssh-agent-login-session-with-windows-10s-new-openssh-and-powers

https://superuser.com/questions/1293725/gpg-agent-under-windows-as-ssh-agent-for-git-bash

Comment: OK, to be precise, your question is about Win32-OpenSSH build of `ssh` – a native Windows application build by Microsoft – as opposite to your other build of OpenSSH that runs on some Linux emulation. These builds probably internally use a different interprocess communication (Win32-OpenSSH will probably use some native Windows API, while the other will use emulation of Linux pipes). – Win32 OpenSSH start its own authentication agent by default (you should see "OpenSSH authentication agent" in your Windows service list). Use Win32-OpenSSH `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-add.exe` to load keys.

Comment: As such your question is not really a programming question. You better ask it on [su].

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - You may be interested in the updated OP and my own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made this work, using the same Cygwin tools (i.e., both `ssh-pageant` and Cygwin OpenSSH client) in a PS session.

So I would do (assuming `ssh-pageant` is already running from Msys2):

```
> cd <dir where ssh-pageant is>
> .\ssh-pageant -r -a "$env:USERPROFILE\tmp\.ssh-pageant-$env:USERNAME"
SSH_AUTH_SOCK='C:\Users\USER1\tmp\.ssh-pageant-USER1'; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
> $env:SSH_AUTH_SOCK='C:\Users\USER1\tmp\.ssh-pageant-USER1'
> .\ssh myserver
Logged in to myserver
```

I have added this to my `profile.ps1` (again, it will work when `ssh-pageant` is already running when I start the PS session)

```
$env:MSYS2_DIR=<mydir>
# Assuming a proxy ssh agent is already running
$env:SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$env:MSYS2_DIR\tmp\.ssh-pageant-$env:USERNAME"
# We have to make sure we use Msys2 OpenSSH ssh client, not Windows OpenSSH ssh client 
function ssh_msys2 {
    & $env:MSYS2_DIR\usr\bin\ssh.exe $args
}
```

---

If an `ssh-pageant` is not yet active, this *should* work (not tested yet; the PID number may be different):

```
> cd <dir where ssh-pageant is>
> .\ssh-pageant -r -a "$env:USERPROFILE\tmp\.ssh-pageant-$env:USERNAME"
SSH_AUTH_SOCK='C:\Users\USER1\tmp\.ssh-pageant-USER1'; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_PAGEANT_PID=714; export SSH_PAGEANT_PID;
echo ssh-pageant pid 714;
> $env:SSH_AUTH_SOCK='C:\Users\USER1\tmp\.ssh-pageant-USER1'
> $env:SSH_PAGEANT_PID=714
> .\ssh myserver
Logged in to myserver
```

Still have to test a couple of points, and automate the operation.

In particular, executing `ssh-pageant`, detecting the PID # if it is returned, and setting environment variable `SSH_PAGEANT_PID` from PS if that is the case.
This is a little bit more cumbersome than in Msys2, since `ssh-pageant` spits something directly executable by bash.