# Mingw-w64: ssh-add works until git fetch (Error connecting to agent: Bad file descriptor)

Tags: git, ssh, git-bash, mingw-w64, ssh-agent

I'm on windows/Git bash/MingW64, trying to automate adding ssh keys for use with git.
I've followed this [guide](https://gist.github.com/bsara/5c4d90db3016814a3d2fe38d314f9c23), altering only the path of my private key file.
It seems to work - when opening git bash I get "succeeded
Identity added: /c/users/...".

`ssh-add -l` also shows that my key was added properly, and the port seems to be configured.

Btw - At this point `$SSH_AGENT_PID` matches the process in `ps` and `$SSH_AUTH_PORT` seems valid (`/tmp/ssh-cEU4wbNe3vo4/agent.927` or similar)

But when I cd into my git repo and run `git fetch` I get:

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

After that, `ssh-add` no longer works, printing:

```
Error connecting to agent: Bad file descriptor
```

Which is strange because both `$SSH_AUTH_PORT` and `$SSH_AGENT_PID` **Did not change** at this point, and I've tried `export`ing them just to be sure.

Starting a new SSH-AGENT and adding my key works in the same terminal session, but trying `git fetch` again will have the same effect.

What is git doing that's messing with the SSH agent?

Comment: Given the error, it seems likely that your ssh agent has crashed. How that might happen, I don't know.

Comment: Possibly useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62937020/reuse-in-powershell-a-running-putty-agent-pageant

Answer (score 7):

Finally after a long search I found it. The Windows update broke my setup , specifically Openssh. I have to enter my passphrase every time since last windows update, and given that your question is fairly recent I suspect the same is true for you.

I think [Win32-OpenSSH#1693](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1693) is related.

In my `~/.gitconfig` in `[core]` there was a line (I don't remember what issue exaclty I had earlier)

```
   sshCommand = C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe
```

Removing it gave this error

```
error: cannot spawn C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh3.exe: No such file or directory
error: cannot spawn C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh3.exe: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

However, replacing it with

```
    sshCommand = "C:/Program\\ Files/Git/usr/bin/ssh.exe"
```

made everything work as I expect.

I think `Error connecting to agent: Bad file descriptor` means something is crashing under the hood, and given that it's since recently, most likely due to the Openssl update.

P.S. You can check if your OpenSSL was updated by checking the "Date modified" of files in `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH`. For me that was very recent and aligns with the moment the ssh-agent stopped functioning.

Answer (score 3):

I am working under Msys2, with ConEmu.
I have recently faced a couple of instances of message `Error connecting to agent: Bad file descriptor`.
After reading this post, I recall trying `git pull` shortly before the error appeared, so it *might* have triggered the error.
I didn't take the time to test systematically to confirm.

As per [Reuse in PowerShell a running PuTTY agent (pageant)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62937020/reuse-in-powershell-a-running-putty-agent-pageant), I checked whether the problem was only with specific combinations agent-client.

[image]

Given WinSCP was working fine (A1-C2 ok), and Msys2 bash `ssh` was not (A1-C3 not ok), I confirmed the problem was with Msys2 bash `ssh-pageant` (A1-P1-C3 broken), even though the same checks as you showed did not suggest any problem.

```
$ env | grep SSH
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/.ssh-pageant-RY16205
SSH_PAGEANT_PID=1615
$ ps
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY    STIME COMMAND
     1618       1    1618      16144  cons0   Jan 25 /usr/bin/bash
     1615       1    1615      15960  ?       Jan 25 /usr/bin/ssh-pageant
```

Since the problem was with `ssh-pageant`, I simply restarted it with

1. Killing the existing `ssh-pageant`

   ```
    $ /usr/bin/ssh-pageant -k
   ```

Note that if, for whatever reason the running `ssh-pageant` is not killed with this command, you can always do that from the *Task manager*.

2. Launch again `ssh-pageant` and set appropriate environment variables

   ```
    $ eval $(/usr/bin/ssh-pageant -r -a "/tmp/.ssh-pageant-$USERNAME")
   ```

or

```
    $ /usr/bin/ssh-pageant -r -a "/tmp/.ssh-pageant-$USERNAME"
    SSH_AUTH_SOCK='/tmp/.ssh-pageant-RY16205'; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
    SSH_PAGEANT_PID=10014; export SSH_PAGEANT_PID;
    echo ssh-pageant pid 10014;
    $ SSH_AUTH_SOCK='/tmp/.ssh-pageant-RY16205'; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
    $ SSH_PAGEANT_PID=10014
```

and it works fine.
Since I did not test thoroughly, I might face the problem again after a new `git pull`.

Note that I use git under Msys2 bash, I don't have a separate git with its own ssh.
So the permanent solution posted in an answer does not seem to apply for me.
I don't *seem* to have Windows OpenSSH either, so [this](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1781) would not apply for me either.
I still have to find the root cause for my problem.

**Related**:

1. https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/ssh-add-l-returning-quot-Error-connecting-to-agent-Bad-file/qaq-p/1654077
2. https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1781

Answer (score 0):

Try first to simplify your %PATH% before launching git bash and your SSH command.

In a new CMD, for testing:

```sh
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%
```

Make sure your environment variables don't have a `GIT_SSH(_xxx)` defined.
Type in that same CMD (before launching the bash)

```
set GIT
```

Then check if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

I got to this problem after turning on openssh in Windows. It works correctly under Powershell, but in git-bash it breaks with OP's error after using a git command.

One solution that worked was setting

```
git config --global core.sshCommand=C:/Program\ Files/Git/usr/bin/ssh.exe
```

but it was breaking git's ssh access in Powershell.

I decided to make an alias in git-bash that is setting ssh.exe on every git command like this:

```
alias git="git -c core.sshCommand='C:/Program\ Files/Git/usr/bin/ssh.exe'"
```

You can put this in .bash_profile file in the user directory and it will run every time you open a git-bash window. The alias will silently replace word git with command in quotation marks.