# Git config - chaining insteadOf does not work

Tags: git, github, ssh, config

I am trying to set up SSH and GPG commit verification on my work Mac laptop. I have two identities I use for `git`, one for work and another for personal account.

I follow steps in my repo that I created exactly for these purposes:
https://github.com/rnag/Mac-Quickstart

Now the issue that I have find (after setting up SSH and GPG successfully) is that when I run `git push` on personal projects, I get this error:

```bash
$ git push
ERROR: Permission to rnag/Mac-Quickstart.git denied to <other user>.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

This is rather ironic since this repo is supposed to help me set up SSH correctly in the first place.

However, that aside, it took me a ***long*** time to debug this issue itself.

I figured it out, that what is happening is that I am using **HTTP remote URLs already** for clone and push purposes.

That is, my current *remote url* looks like this:

```bash
$ grep url .git/config
    url = https://github.com/rnag/Mac-Quickstart.git
```

Due to the **git config** the script have help me set up, when I run `git remote -v` it shows me SSH url now:

```bash
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:rnag/Mac-Quickstart.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:rnag/Mac-Quickstart.git (push)
```

But that's not *exactly* how I'd want SSH url to look. If we take a look at my *merged git config*, these are the entries it has for `insteadOf`:

```ini
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/

[url "git@github.com-rnag"]
    insteadOf = git@github.com

[url "git://"]
    insteadOf = https://
```

So we have SSH urls replaced correctly -- `git@github.com/<user>/<repo>` becomes `git@github.com-rnag/<user>/<repo>`, as I'd want it to.

But with HTTPS urls, the `insteadOf` set up does not chain and work as expected. For example, it replaces `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>` to `git@github.com/<user>/<repo>` as expected, but it doesn't do the **second replacement** in my git config as I expect it to, and replace `git@github.com/<user>/<repo>` with `git@github.com-rnag/<user>/<repo>`.

Of course, this poses a problem because in my `~/.ssh/config` file, it is looking for a host to be like `github.com-<user>` format. It sees `github.com` and because there is no entry, I assume it uses whatever default SSH identity file that it wants to.

So there is issue with `insteadOf` due to me having set up multiple identities with `git`.

I searched online for long time after spending a long time debugging the root cause of this issue which turn out because I was using an HTTPS url for git, but I couldn't find anything that mentioned it.

I am not too familiar with git docs on `insteadOf`, or why it would not chain or work as expected in this scenario. If any seasoned git expert has tips on this, it would be great to know about it. Thanks!

Comment: `git://` refers to the Git protocol, which is insecure (and therefore not supported by any public hosting provider). Don't use that.

Comment: @JimRedmond gotcha, I wasn't aware. I think I just saw that a lot everywhere when I was searching online. That said, it seem that particular `insteadOf` wouldn't be relevant to the issue itself (actually I can probably omit it, doesn't seem to apply in this case).

Comment: I did a quick experiment and found that `insteadOf`s do not chain. The first one applied, stop. Most probably to avoid complications like, e.g., loops. That what you have to live with. They do not chain so you need to rewrite your config accordingly.

Comment: @phd Yeah, looks like this is indeed the case. I didn't search git docs too long but yeah intuition would tell me that `insteadOf`s would chain - seems to be a bug that this is not the case. I ended up rewriting my git config to work around this limitation, but I do think its a shame that a quick search online doesn't turn up any results on it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**. For now -- unless someone else can offer a better solution -- the workaround I have in place is to:

1. Remove all instances of `insteadOf` everywhere, including the **global git config** at `~/.gitconfig`.

   It might be helpful to run the following command to find all occurrences of `insteadOf` and discover the source of it:

   ```bash
   git config -l --show-origin | grep insteadof
   ```
2. Add the following to your **user-specific** git config. This is not your global git config at `~/.gitconfig` but your *github-username-* or *project-* scoped config, e.g. for your Git project.

   For me, that was located at `~/.dotfiles/Personal-github.gitconfig`. Then I opened it in a text editor, and replaced all usages of `insteadOf` with these lines:

   > Replace `<user>` with your GitHub username.

   ```ini
   [url "git@github.com-<user>:"]
       insteadOf = git@github.com:
       insteadOf = https://github.com/
   ```
3. If all is good, you should receive a ***success*** message when running `git push`. You can try that out when you have no local changes and nothing staged, and it should now not print that error message from before:

   ```
   $ git push
   Everything up-to-date
   ```