# Bash script running python scripts

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I new to bash script, and found one of the code from stackoverflow. I merge it with my script, it doesn't run python. When I try to echo, it is always going to "Good". When I tried to run `ps -ef | grep runserver*` this always came out and causing the python script not running.

```
root      1133  0.0  0.4  11988  2112 pts/0    S+   02:58   0:00 grep --color=auto runserver.py
```

Here is my code:-

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE='runserver*'

if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
then
    python /var/www/html/rest/runserver.py
    python /var/www/html/rest2/runserver.py
else
    echo "Good"
fi
```

Comment: the answers are here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903354/bash-script-to-check-running-process

Comment: Did this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377109/shell-script-execute-a-python-program-from-within-a-shell-script

Comment: @HaifengZhang I used that example, and it didn't work... that's why I'm asking for another solution

Comment: @Aison I can run my python scripts if condition is true, but now it always goes to else condition

Comment: Can you provide the output of `ps ax | grep -v grep | grep runserver`?

Comment: @JoseRaulBarreras empty

Answer (score 0):

If you are more familiar with python, try this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys

process = os.popen("ps aux | grep -v grep | grep WHATEVER").read().splitlines()

if len(process) == 2:
  print "WHATEVER is running - nothing to do"
else:
  os.system("WHATEVER &")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the following code what you want?

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVER='runserver*'
CC=`ps ax|grep -v grep|grep "$SERVER"`
if [ "$CC" = "" ]; then
    python /var/www/html/rest/runserver.py
    python /var/www/html/rest2/runserver.py
else
    echo "good"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

@NickyMan, the problem is related to the logic in the shell script. Your program don't find *runserver* and always says "Good".
In this code, if you don't find the server, then exec *runserver*.

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE='runserver*'

if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
then
    echo "Good"
else
    python /var/www/html/rest/runserver.py
    python /var/www/html/rest2/runserver.py
fi
```