# How do I make a bash script to start running when Firefox starts and stop running when Firefox is closed?

Tags: bash, firefox, scripting, fedora

I have a script on my Fedora PC that I want to run only while Firefox is active.
I want to find a way to monitor the PC for Firefox's status.

Once Firefox starts, I want the script to start.
When Firefox is closed, I want the script to stop.
If Firefox is reopened in the same session, I want the script to run again, and repeat the process as many times as necessary.

Let's call the script "bash_script.sh". For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
Start monitoring FF status
When FF starts, do something
When FF is closed, stop doing it and continue monitoring FF status
```

So I have the following questions:

1. Is there a way to achieve this with a bash script? Can you please give me an example?
2. Should I change the permissions to 777 and put this script on crontab?
3. If yes, what syntax should I use? If no, how else can I achieve that process?

I am a complete beginner with bash scripting and I have no idea where to start!
Apologies if this is a very easy question.

Comment: See See [Linux Script to check if process is running and act on the result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20162678/4154375) and [Bash script to check running process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2903354/4154375).

Answer (score 2):

Simply use this wrapper script accessible before `/usr/bin` in your `PATH`:

`firefox`:

```
#!/bin/bash

code_before_running_FF
/usr/bin/firefox & pid=$!
wait $pid
code_after_running_FF
```

If you want to track `syscalls`, you can use:

```
strace -ff -s 1000 -o /tmp/trace-FF /usr/bin/firefox
```